# IE6: select inside jQuery tabs does not render dropdown list

Tags: jquery-ui, internet-explorer-6, jquery-tabs

I have a form inside jQuery tabs; I create tabs in a simple way:

```
$("#tabs").tabs({selected: 1});
```

The selected index 1 is the tab where form is placed. The problem is, on remote computer with IE6 both selects only display a small blank line instead of list with options when dropdown arrow is clicked:

[Incorrect dropdown http://queen3.at.tut.by/DropDownIE6jQuery.PNG](http://queen3.at.tut.by/DropDownIE6jQuery.PNG)

The options are there in page source, and everything actually works on other machines, in other browsers and also in IE6 (though I use IETester).

Everything also works if I

- remove tabs creation, that is .tabs() - options do appear and work; or
- first select tab without form (tab 0), and then click on it - options do appear and work

  - only when clicking; programmatic .tabs("select", 1) after tabs creation doesn't help

Does anyone know what can cause this? Is it IE6 bug or something with my scripts?

Update: hm, thanks to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982859/strange-bug-in-ie6-for-jquery-tab), I found it's something with my CSS - if I disable Site.css it works. I thought about scripts only. Still have to find out what's that.

Update: OK, this was caused by this CSS rule:

```
body { font-size: 0.7em; }
```

It works if I set 0.8 or greater, but for 0.7 and less IE6 does the indicated bug.

Can someone explain this? Yes it is IE6 - weird by definition, but **this one** is too weird in my opinion.

Comment: Interestingly the drop down will display if it's on a tab other than the first. I'm currently looking for a solution.

Comment: See http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4734

Comment: Hm, very nice, I'd accept if it was an answer because the link is very interesting, especially that this happens only on few machines. I've added my case to that ticket.

Comment: I've got this strange issue too, but only on a machine with DPI 120 set. My case is that only one of the selects under the tab is affected (and only in one page! Other page with similar layout has no problem) I tried to adjust font size but has no luck. The selects is a dynamic one which will populate ajaxly on page load. My solution is that after population, I set size $('#select').attr('size', 2).attr('size', 1); I'm still scratching my head.

Comment: Further study show that it's a kind of speed problem?? In the problem page I first init tabs in doc ready, then init other UI and finally the dynamic select. When I change the order of init tab-->dynamic selects-->other UI, the problem go away. Still wondering why.

Answer (score 0):

I have also ran into this exact problem, although I couldn't fix it by altering any body font sizes, I did manage to get around it using the (slightly modified) "Ugly hack" method as described in the [dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4734](http://dev.jqueryui.com/ticket/4734) link, posted by CiscoIPPhone:

```
// Ugly hack to switch tabs in IE6, fixing select menu bug.
  if($.browser.msie && $.browser.version.substr(0, 1) <= 6) {
    $("#tabs").tabs({ selected: 1 }); 
    setTimeout(function() {
       $("#tabs").tabs("select", 0);
    }, 10);
  }
```

Seems as though the timeout is the key to avoiding this bug.

Answer (score 0):

I found that this workaround fixed the issue on some machines, but not on others.

My solution was to hide all the select elements initally in the style sheet, then after calling `$( "#tabs" ).tabs()` I use `$('select').show()` to display them.

That fixed it for me.