# Dropdown not working in some IE 6 browsers

Tags: html, select, internet-explorer-6

We unfortunately find ourselves having to support our product in IE 6 because some of our largest users use it. One of them called today and told me that one of the dropdowns doesn't work when he clicks on it - it simply selects the first item.

I checked the markup and the entire contents of the select control are being sent:

```
<select onchange="SDateFilter_S('#ctlDateRange')" size="1" name="ctlDateRange" style="width:100px;">
            <option selected="selected" value="0">
                All Dates
            </option><option value="1">
                Within
            </option><option value="2">
                Before
            </option><option value="3">
                After
            </option><option value="4">
                Between
            </option><option value="5">
                Last
            </option><option value="6">
                Since
            </option>
        </select>
```

This is done in ASP .NET but I am fairly certain the issue isn't with ASP .NET as when I try it in my copy of IE 6, it works correctly.

Do you have any idea what would cause a dropdown list in some copies of IE 6 to effectively not work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears this issue was caused because, under some unknown circumstances on some versions of IE 6, the fonts don't inherit as they should. When I force-set the fonts, the dropdowns started working as they should.

Comment: what do u do to force set the fonts?

Answer (score 0):

The client may have addins, settings, or policies that are interfering with the dropdown.

Comment: I was fairly certain this was the issue but I don't know which addons, settings or policies can cause this. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

I would think that the problem lies in the onchange event for the dropdown as it seems unlikely that a normal dropdown would behave in that way. I would suggest going into a remote assistance session with the client if possible and checking their IE settings and compare them to your settings. Also check any other dropdowns to see if they have the same issue.

Comment: Other dropdowns don't work but they make no sense and there's no rhyme or reason as to why they don't work for this client. All of them work for me. I did come across this after much searching and the problem is exactly similar to mine but we don't use em sizing and are not using the jquery tab control (but the dropdown does exactly that): 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2182964/ie6-select-inside-jquery-tabs-does-not-render-dropdown-list

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Does your `onchange` event meddle with the selection? Does the function complete, or die on the way? That's where I would look.

Comment: It was occuring even before onchange could be triggered - you'd click the arrow and nothing was there so nothing ever changed.